# Android delete internal data of other Apps without root

Tags: android

I'm developing some Android app, and I need to delete all internal data( logout from FB, Twitter, clear browser history etc..)

Is it possible to do this without rooted phone?
Or is it possible to create some kind of virtual guest user and delete data after session programmatically?

Comment: I don't need to delete my app's data, i need to delete from apps like Facebook, Chrome..

Comment: Sorry, I haven't grasped the question completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete data from other apps without root from your app. The only way is using settings-> apps-> appName->clear data...

Android has a private directory for every app, and only this app can access to this directory (instead of you have your phone rooted).

Reading [Android - Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), it says:

*You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.*

If you don't have the phone rooted, I think you cannot do it...